# Bootstrap doesn't save entities

Tags: grails

I'm completely new to Grails and I'm doing the tutorial "Getting started with Grails Second Edition" by Scott Davis and Jason Rudolph.

When I'm setting up the BootStrap it seems like grails doesn't save the entities and I can't see them in my application. 
I've already tried save(failOnError:true), but it compiles and saves without any errors.

Here is the code of BootStrap.groovy

```
package racetrack
import grails.util.GrailsUtil

class BootStrap {
  def init = { servletContext ->
    switch(GrailsUtil.environment){
     case "development":

       def jane = new Runner(
                  firstName:"Jane",
                  lastName:"Doe",
                  dateOfBirth:(new Date() - 365*30),
                  gender:"F",
                  address:"123 Main St",
                  city:"Goose",
                  state:"NC",
                  zipcode:"12345",
                  email:"jane@whereever.com"
                  )
       jane.save()
       if(jane.hasErrors()){
         println jane.errors
       }

       def trot = new Race(
                  name:"Turkey Trot",
                  startDate:(new Date() + 90),
                  city:"Duck",
                  state:"NC",
                  distance:5.0,
                  cost:20.0,
                  maxRunners:350
                  )
       trot.save()
       if(trot.hasErrors()){
         println trot.errors
       }

      def reg = new Registration(
                paid:false,
                runner:jane,
                race:trot
                )
      reg.save()
      if(reg.hasErrors()){
        println reg.errors
      }

      break
    case "production" : break
   }
  }
  def destroy = { }
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

are you in development mode?

Mybe you should add a log.debug or println statement to see if your code gets executed.

and have your tried a `.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)`? the flush might help

Comment: The failOnError was a big help as it was able to show me the validation errors which was preventing the entity to be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Use enums instead of Strings. Enums fit best in switch-case scenario and you can avoid mistakes. Maybe `GrailsUtil.environment` returns `DEVELOPMENT` not `development`? Instead of:

```
case "development"
```

use

```
case Environment.DEVELOPMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the grails.util.Environment enum doesn't work as is. Because the [grails.util.GrailsUtil.environment](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/grails/util/Environment.html) returns a string, not an Environment.

You are more or less forced using strings.

Answer (score 0):

Though old I thought it might help if I posted something I just found :)

```
if (GrailsUtil.developmentEnv){
    // do dev stuff
} 
else {
    // do other stuff
}
```